# Why window.opener.location.reload(true) / opener.location.reload(true) sometimes won't work?

Tags: javascript, php, html, popup

I need to refresh parent page from pop up, then i use window.opener.location.reload(true);
It work's fine, until i found it sometimes it was not work (doesn't reload)

Here is my code

```
<script>
    function reloadOpener() {
        window.opener.location.reload(true);
    }
</script>



<tr>
    <td colspan="4">
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['DETAIL_ROW'])) {
            echo $objButton->editToListButton($_SESSION['CONFIRMATION_FLAG'], 'EDIT_TO_LIST', 'reloadOpener()');
        } else {
            echo $objButton->addToListButton($_SESSION['CONFIRMATION_FLAG'], 'ADD_TO_LIST', 'reloadOpener()');
        } ?>                    
    </td>               
</tr>   




 /*
      Button untuk menambahkan detail ke daftar detail
      return button
     */

    public function addToListButton($confirmationFlag, $buttonName, $functionName) {
        $disabled = '';

        if ($confirmationFlag == constant("Y.ENUM")) {
            $disabled = 'disabled';
        }

        $button = "<input name='$buttonName' type='submit' class='BUTTON' id='$buttonName' value='" . constant('TAMBAHKAN_KE_DAFTAR.CON') . "' " . $disabled . " onclick='$functionName' />";

        return $button;
    }

    /*
      Button untuk mengubahkan detail ke daftar detail
      return button
     */

    public function editToListButton($confirmationFlag, $buttonName, $functionName) {
        $disabled = '';

        if ($confirmationFlag == constant("Y.ENUM")) {
            $disabled = 'disabled';
        }

        $button = "<input name='$buttonName' type='submit' class='BUTTON' id='$buttonName' value='" . constant('UBAHKAN_KE_DAFTAR.CON') . "' " . $disabled . " onclick='$functionName' />";

        return $button;
    }
```

When i clicked add or edit, it will trigger reload opener and refresh opener page.
i try 20 times, about 1 or 2 times was fail.

anyone can help?

Browser = firefox and IE

extra question, what is the different between .windows and .self ?
can i use self.opener.location.reload(true); ?

Comment: `self` is a property of `window` containing a reference to `window`. The only difference is, that you can override `self` (in most browsers), hence it's not always reliable to refer `window` via `self`. Unfortenately I don't have an answer to your actual problem.

Comment: waiting for answer :D